# How to run command so that it runs even if console is closed?

Tags: unix, centos

I am deleting one folder on my server. The size of that folder is around 100GB. 
I am using `rm -rf cache`
Is there is anyway that even if I close the console or disconnects the netwrok, the commands keep running until it got completed?

My server is on CENTOS v6

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nohup rm -rf cache > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: do I have write `> /dev/null 2>&1` also ?

Comment: Needs an `& disown` at the end.  (Not all incarnations of `nohup` fork into the background.)

Comment: @Zack can you please suggest your answer on this also

Comment: @Yogus That would be pointless. This answer is essentially correct, I only have a refinement to suggest.

Comment: @Zack if next time I loggin to console, how can I check if the process is still running or not ?

Comment: @Yogus (Why are you capitalizing my handle?) You want [`ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) for that.

Comment: Thanks you so much . I have corrected the capitilazation too.

Answer (score 2):

To run them in the background you can use '&' symbol along with your command
As follows,

```
nohup rm -rf cache &
```

You can read the status/output of your command at run time too

```
tail -10 nohup.out
```

this will give you the run time output (like output console).

Hope this helps.

Comment: `tail: cannot open `nohup' for reading: No such file or directory
'

Comment: you have to use like nohup.out .. please see my edited answer